# Is this html tag well formatted

Tags: html

Our design department gave me a code to add to a page and I am kind of new to the design part of it and stuff... but is this a valid tag and what does it mean <--if subcontent add rel="test1"-->. Is this somthing that I can just leave like that (it is evaluating correctly as it is) or do I actually need to do something so that that part does something?

```
<li class="test1"><a href="" <!-- if subcontent add rel="test1" -->>test 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Oh ok, so i guess I need to see if there is subcontent and if so I should plug in a "rel="blah". Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the browser may display correctly, but the w3c says it's invalid
the right way must be:

```
<li class="test1">
  <!-- if subcontent add rel="test1" to the anchor ie:<a rel="text"> -->
  <a href="#">test 1</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the W3 validation service to determine whether your html is valid. This tests entire pages, not single lines.

http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking what the `<!-- -->` tags are? If so they are `html` comments it probably shouldn't be left inside the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. The correct version would have the comment outside of the a tag:

```
<li class="test1"><a href=""><!-- if subcontent add rel="test1" -->test 1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

this looks like an HTML comment!

Answer (score 1):

Anything within `<!--  -->` are comments and are compleatly ignored by the browser. Its for human use only. Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_rel.asp) at what the rel tag does